# Installing libapache2-mod-passenger to Debian Lenny with apache2-mpm-itk

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, passenger

I'm trying to install [libapache2-mod-passenger](http://packages.debian.org/lenny-backports/libapache2-mod-passenger) (from backports) to a Debian Lenny system containing [apache2-mpm-itk](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/apache2-mpm-itk). What happens is this:

```
# aptitude install libapache2-mod-passenger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
Reading task descriptions... Done  
The following packages are BROKEN:
  libapache2-mod-php5 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-worker{a} javascript-common{a} libapache2-mod-passenger 
  libjs-prototype{a} librack-ruby{a} librack-ruby1.8{a} wwwconfig-common{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-mpm-itk{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 7 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 792kB of archives. After unpacking 3191kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libapache2-mod-php5: Depends: apache2-mpm-prefork (> 2.0.52) but it is not installable or
                                apache2-mpm-itk but it is not installable
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Remove the following packages:
libapache2-mod-php5

Score is 119

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

As far as I understand, this is because `mod_passenger` requires Apache version >=2.2.9-9, but the `apache2-mpm-itk` of Lenny is only version 2.2.6-02. This is at least a [reported bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=556230), and even claims to be fixed, but apparently has been [reported again](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg796890.html). Is there any trick to get `mod_passenger` installed while keeping the `mpm-itk` flavor of Apache? Apparently Passenger would work with Apache 2.2.6-02, the problem is just that the package dependency is set to wrong version.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the package dependencies apt-get source package-name
cd debian
nano control and change version requirements
cd ..
apt-get build-dep package-name
apt-get install build-essential devscripts fakeroot
debuild

for more on rolling your own debs here's a tutorial:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51003

disregard the setting up directories as that's done by apt-get source

Comment: for all ruby/rails stuff i use lucid LTS and gem for the installs

Comment: Thanks; I have no previous experience of de(re?)building Debian packages. Is it really as simple as those couple of commands? Does it make a `.deb` file, which I then install with `dpkg`?

Comment: it can be that simple...sometimes it isn't. added a couple lines since your box hasn't been used for this before...and yes it produces debs...you are re-building a package but you are deb-building hence debuild.